# Black to move. Find all possible #-1

Tags: story, chess

In the middle of researching a new chess AI by pitting bots against each other, the researchers notice the below position just before Black wins on the next move.

They are confounded for a minute before realising what had happened.

What could this move have been?

[image]

Comment: edited due to comments in answer - now puzzle should have intended answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found one:

> cxb3 e.p

> Because the board is oriented with white at the bottom. There aren't enough missing white pieces or pawns to allow for the central pawn formation. Also, b4 is the only possible prior move that would allow a mate in 1.

Comment: Actually, you'd have to [prove](https://www.chess.com/blog/Rocky64/chess-problem-conventions-re-castling-and-capturing-en-passant#:~:text=The%20convention%20for%20en%20passant%20captures%20applies%20to,last%20move%20was%20a%20double-step%20by%20that%20pawn.) that white's last move was indeed b2-b4 which I'm not sure you can.

Comment: You only have to find the possible mate (note the question phrasing). I wasn't necessarily looking for a full blown set of moves to show it is (although that would complete the answer properly)

Comment: @Shuri2060 The phrasing of the question is not clear enough to override a well-established convention. Indeed, by that convention the e.p. capture and hence the mate in one is not possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I asked for 'all possible #-1'. The mate in the above answer IS possible IF the previous move was b4. To be certain - one can provide a set of moves that leads to such a situation.

Comment: @Shuri2060 It's simple enough: As you don't know whether the last move was b2-b4 or not you also don't know whether the e.p. is possible or not. And the convention is that you may not assume that the last move was b2-b4 unless you can prove it was.

Comment: I am not aware of this convention you state. Please suggest a better phrasing to make it clear that it isn't what I meant. By 'possible' I mean to condition over possible past moves as well. For example fxe4# is not possible for this reason.

Comment: It's actually codified: Chapter IV, Article 16 (2) in the [Handbook Of Chess Composition](https://www.wfcc.ch/wfcc-about/hcc/). I can't think of a good way of phrasing it that is unambiguous without giving away the answer.

Comment: I can't see it in that handbook, but is it also standard to state board orientation? In which case this puzzle fails to be standard anyways.

Comment: @Shuri2060 Quoting from the handbook based on loopy's comments: "En-passant convention. An en-passant capture on the first move is permitted only if it can be proved that the last move was the double step of the pawn which is to be captured". You don't have to follow this convention, anyway, but it's a standard assumption for people familiar with chess compositions, so you received this pushback, hehe. But yeah, it's not really satisfying to say that an enpassant is the answer without proving that it's possible, the best we can do is to assume that the puzzle has a solution, but that's not fun

Comment: @loopywalt justhalf Thanks for the information. Thought of a way to respin the puzzle with the intended answer by a story - edited.

Comment: Nice edit! It makes this question-answer valid now. Nice problem

Answer (score 0):

For completeness of [Herb's solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/120228/30178)

> To show the position is reachable where en passant is the previous move
>  1. a4 b5 2. e4 bxa4 3. d4 e5 4. d5 f5 5. c3 Bb4 6. cxb4 a5 7. b5 Ke7 8. Qh5 Kf6 9. Qe8 g5 10. h4 gxh4 11. Bh6 h3 12. Bf8 Kg5 13. g4 Kf4 14. Kd2 c5 15. Rh2 Nf6 16. Rg2 Nh5 17. Rh2 Ng3 18. Kc3 c4 19. b6 Rg8 20. Ra3 h5 21. Rg2 h2 22. fxg3+ Ke3 23. Rb3 a3 24. Rb5 a4 25. Rc5 a2 26. Nd2 a3 27. b7 h4 28. g5 h3 29. g6 Rg7 30. g4 Rh7 31. g7 Rh4 32. g5 Rg4 33. Rf2 Ra5 34. g6 Na6 35. Ngf3 Rg1 36. Ng5 Rh1 37. Nf7 Qh4 38. Rg2 Qe1 39. Rg5 d6 40. Rh5 Nc7 41. Kb4 Rb5+ 42. Ka4 Rb3 43. Ka5 Rc3 44. Kb6 Na6 45. Ka7 Rc1 46. Rh8 Nc7 47. Kb8 Be6 48. Nb3 Qd1 49. Ra5 Qe1 50. Nc5 Qd1 51. Nd7 Qe1 52. Kc8 Qd1 53. Ra8 Nb5 54. Nh6 Qe1 55. Ng8 Nc3 56. Kc7 Qd1 57. Rd8 Qe1 58. Kc8 Nb5 59. Be2 Nc7 60. Bh5 Na6 61. Bg4 Kd2 62. Bh5 Qe2 63. Bf3 Kd1 64. Bg4 Rg1 65. Bh5 Rh1 66. b4

Comment: Feel free to edit a shorter one.

Answer (score -1):

I only find fxe4#
Which open your rook to deliver a checkmate

Comment: The move you propose is legal, but isn't #. The other answer explains why (but spoiler).

Comment: What is the response to that if it is not a checkmate

Comment: Your answer looks right but is based on a mistaken assumption - see the second spoilerblock in the other answer.